# Laravel Sms Content Manipulate

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, data-manipulation, smsmanager

here is part of sms of notification class.How can I make it disaapeared this strong tags in sms like here

```
public function toTelinka($notifiable): SmsMessage
{
    return (new SmsMessage())
       ->setContent( __('notification.backup.sql_db_backup_task_added.sms_content', [
            'target_user_name_and_email' => $this->targetUser->name . '(' . $this->targetUser->email . ')',
             'sql_db_backup_task_name' =>'<strong>'.$this->addedTask->task->name.'</strong>'//goon some text in lang file                
        ]))
        ->setRecipients([$notifiable->phone]);
}`
```

Comment: perhaps look at php `strip_tags`

Comment: don't work and it isnot true function so strip_tags delete my strong tags

Comment: 'deleted_file_count' => strip_tags('<strong>' .$this->data->deletedCount. '</strong>',['strong'])